# SOAP request by JAVA vs PROC SOAP in SAS

Tags: java, soap, sas

We have a SAS code where Proc SOAP is deployed to send a request to outer system and we want to utilize java code to perform a request instead of PROC SOAP in SAS.

What would be a solution for this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is important to note that PROC SOAP (and PROC HTTP) are just SAS wrappers around Java libraries.  So you asking to reinvent the wheel.  Though sometimes SAS's wheels are less than round...

Solution 1:
Write a command line Java program that makes the call.  Have it take in a text file as input and output a text file with the result.  Use a Data Step to create the input file, an `x` command to call the program, and another Data Step to read the resulting text file.

Solution 2:
Write a simple object in Java that does the call.  Use the Java Object elements in a Data Step to instantiate the object, populate the appropriate variables, and run the appropriate method.  See documentation here: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lecompobjref/67221/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1p8iy7j6aa64mn13g6a1cvauwww.htm

Option 1 is more "old school" SAS and shouldn't be too hard.  Your Java programmer and SAS programmer just have to agree on the input and output formats.

Option 2 is more involved and will require closer working between Java and SAS programmer.

In option 2 the SAS code and Java are more tightly coupled.  For that reason (and a reason why you would use SOAP services to begin with), I would pick option 1.